# Replace a range of text with special characters using sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace a range of text with sed containing special characters.

I have the following output:

```
"Users" "/Users/Users"   SERVER1
"Roaming Profiles" "/Roaming Profiles/Roaming Profiles"   SERVER2
```

I would like it to be like this:

```
Users SERVER1
Roaming Profiles SERVER2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -r 's/"([^"]*)"([^"]*"){2}[[:space:]]*/\1 /' file
Users SERVER1
Roaming Profiles SERVER2
```

#### How it works

The sed substitution command has the form `s/old/new/`.  The regular expression for `old` has the following parts:

- `"([^"]*)"`  -- This matches the first string in quotes and saves it in group 1.
- `([^"]*"){2}`  -- This matches the second quoted string (including the spaces which precede it).
- `[[:space:]]*`  -- This matches the spaces which follow the second quoted string.

The regular expression for `new` is simply `\1` which is a space followed by the first quoted string which, via the parenthesis, we had saved in group 1.

#### Mac OSX or other BSD platforms

On OSX, try:

```
sed -E 's/"([^"]*)"([^"]*"){2}[[:space:]]*/\1 /' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Awk:

```
awk -F\" '{print $2,$5}' file
```